# jquery disable specific submit button

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of divs with the same class on one page that have a form with input fields and a submit button in them. I check with jquery for each input field if it is empty, and I want the submit button in that specific div to be disabled when theres an empty field in that div. Got this so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.shipdiv input').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == ''){
    $(this).css("background-color","#ff0000");
    $(this).parent('.contact-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
});
   });
```

When theres a field empty it colors red, and then I try to disable the submitbutton that is in its parent. But thats not working. Anyone got an idea on how to do this?

HTML looks somthing like this:

```
<div class="shipdiv">
<form name="order_002" method="post" action="">
<input type="textfield" class="ship_data" name="bedrijfsnaam"/>
<input type="textfield" class="ship_data" name="straat" />
<input type="textfield" class="ship_data" name="postcode"/>
<input type="submit" name="ship-submit" id="ship-submit" class="contact-button" value="Aanmelden">
</form>
</div>
```

And then with several of these divs.

Comment: Could you post some of your HTML?

Comment: thats generated with php but ill try to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
 $(this).parent('div').find('.contact-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or use closest:

```
 $(this).closest('div').find('.contact-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by finding the parent div, relative to the current input, then finding the button within the div.

```
$(this).parents('.shipdiv').find('.contact-button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Side note: `.prop('disabled', true)` is preferred to `.attr()`.